# Call by value vs call by reference while dealing with binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree, function-call

When we want to change the value of an ordinary variable by in a function we pass it using call by reference. But I am not able to understand the intricacies when we have to pass a pointer variable(like a node of a binary tree) using call by refence. I understand that if we want to modify the poiter variable to point to another node we have to use call by reference. But what if we have to modify the data element of the root. I thought that to change it also we would need a call by reference. But the following code snippet is giving an output of 10, 10, 10 even though I have passed the root node of the tree using call by value in the function modifyTree. Am I missing something over here?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct node
{
int data;
struct node* left;
struct node* right;
};

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the
given data and NULL left and right pointers. */
struct node* newNode(int data)
{
struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

node->data = data;
node->left = NULL;
node->right = NULL;
return(node);
}

/*  This function sets the data fields of some of the nodes of tree to 10*/
void modifyTree(struct node* node)
{

node->data = 10;
node->left->data = 10;
node->right->data = 10;
}

int main()
{
struct node *root = newNode(1);
root->left            = newNode(2);
root->right          = newNode(3);
root->left->left     = newNode(4);
root->left->right   = newNode(5);

modifyTree(root);

printf("%d\n", root->data);
printf("%d\n", root->left->data);
printf("%d\n", root->right->data);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `modifyTree(struct node* node)`: So you *are* passing a pointer to the `root` node to `modifyTree`. So it *is* a 'call by reference'.

Comment: I have passed the root element as modifyTree(root) and not like modifyTree(&root). So it's a call by value.

Comment: C does not support call by reference. Pointers are not quite the same as references in C++. See http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passbyref.html.

Comment: The root element is a `struct node`. You passed a pointer to the root element. i.e. `struct node *` type.

Comment: @Prateek - In C, whatever you pass is 'copied' when passed to the callee (like ThomSmith said). If you pass a pointer, the pointer is copied. But the new pointer is still pointing to the *same* `struct node`. i.e. the root element is *not* copied.

Comment: @Prateek - to be more clear, the variable `root` in your example is *not* the root element. It is a pointer to the root element. The *actual* root element is `*root`, i.e. the location that `root` (the pointer) points to. So when you call `modifyTree(root)` you have *not* passed the root element. You have passed a pointer to it.

Comment: Thanx Arjun I am able to understand it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the **pointer** by value, but the pointer still points at the same thing.  I'll use some hypothetical values to demonstrate.

In `main` you allocate a new `struct node`.  Let's say it gets created at memory location `0x12345`.  So now your `struct node *root` contains `0x12345`.

You now call `modifyTree(root);`.  `root` gets passed **by value** to the `root` argument of `modifyTree`.

That `root` now contains `0x12345`.  *It's pointing at the same memory location.*

So when you access that location with `node->data = 10`, you are accessing the same memory you created in `main`.

Answer (score 3):

Passing a pointer by value means the called function receives the exact same pointer value that the caller used, so any accesses through that pointer will refer to the same memory.

You would need a double pointer if you wanted the function to modify the pointer *value* the caller has (for instance by allocating a new tree, thus "creating" a new pointer value).

Answer (score 0):

You pass the pointer by value yes, but what you are changing inside the modifyTree function are elements of the struct that the pointer is pointing to. Passing the pointer to the struct by value will not prevent you from changing the internal contents of the struct being pointed at by your parameter. If it were the pointer **itself** that you were changing, then you would see the behaviour that you are expecting.